# Looking for Clone() implementation with derived return Type

Tags: c#, abstract, icloneable

I am sure this must be a duplicate, but I can't find the answer:

If I have two classes:

```
public class BASE
{
    public BASE() {};
    public abstract BASE clone();
}


public class CHILD : BASE
{

    public CHILD() : base() {}
    public override BASE clone()
    {
        return new CHILD();
    }
}
```

I have to make an explicit conversion every time I want to clone an object of type CHILD like:

```
var a = new CHILD();
CHILD b = a.clone() as CHILD;
```

Is there a way to avoid this conversion?
I would like to be able to write:

```
var original = new CHILD();
BASE copy1 = original.clone();
CHILD copy2 = original.clone();
```

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: It is ok to have `BASE` instead of `CHILD` due to polymorphism I think. Why do you want `CHILD` type? But there is a way to do that though... use method *hiding* instead of method *overriding*

Comment: Polymorphism allows me to write `CHILD c = new CHILD(); BASE b = c` but not the other way around. I can't assign a `BASE` object to a `CHILD` variable. That's why I always have to make the conversion when I clone a CHILD.

Comment: I see, in that case, use `generic` is your option

Comment: You can't have one method return two different types without any kind of casting or conversion.  While generics can get around this somewhat, it comes with it's own hidden set of restrictions.  Why is using the `as CHILD` so bad?

Comment: Because I am lazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid this conversion?

Not by overloading `Clone` - you can't overload a method just by changing its return type.  Use a different method instead:

```
public class CHILD : BASE
{

    public CHILD() : base() {}
    public BASE clone() { return this.cloneChild();}
    public CHILD cloneChild()
    {
        return new CHILD();
    }
}
```

If you want to enforce that behavior on *all* inherited classes you could make `BASE` generic:

```
public abstract class BASE<T> where T:BASE<T>
{
    public BASE() {}
    public abstract T clone();
}


public class CHILD : BASE<CHILD>
{

    public CHILD() : base() {}
    public override CHILD clone()
    {
        return new CHILD();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need `CHILD` type instead of `BASE` type in the `clone`, then you need to do method *hiding* instead of method *overriding*. You should remove the `override` keyword and use `new` instead:

```
public class BASE
{
    public BASE() {};
    public abstract BASE clone();
}

public class CHILD : BASE
{

    public CHILD() : base() {}
    public new CHILD clone()
    {
        return new CHILD();
    }
}
```

Comment: So long as you don't have a reference to a `CHILD` through a variable of type `BASE` - you'd get the `clone` method on `BASE` called, which might not correctly clone the `CHILD` instance.

Comment: @JamesThorpe my apologize, what I meant was actually `CHILD` - thanks for the comment

Comment: You still have the same problem.  If you have an instance of `CHILD` but the code is storing it in a `BASE` variable, you'll end up calling `BASE.clone` on a `CHILD` instance.  Chances are this isn't going to give correct behaviour.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I agree, actually the better solution for this case is generic. Seems like some other people have mentioned it...

Answer (score 0):

C# does not support return type covariance. You can try this workaround (using generics):

```
public class Base<T> {
    public abstract T Clone()
}

public class Child : Base<Child> {
    public override Child Clone() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```